# internationalization and localization - multi language support

Tags: android, ios, localization, internationalization

How does internationalization/localization works for an ios and android microblogging app?

is it possible that a user can type the message in his/her native language and  rest of the world can read it in the language it wants ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Internalization and Localization in iOS and android you have to specify the text in all languages you support i.e a copy of every TEXT in one language should be translated into another. I have provided links below which will help you to get started with it in respective mobile platform.

If you want to translate dynamic text, i.e if you want to translate one user's message to any other language of recipient user. You should consider using [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs)

iOS:

- [About Internationalization and Localization - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Internationalization - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/)

Android:

- [Supporting Different Languages | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)
- [Localizing with Resources | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)